# jQuery Showing Hidden Element - Jumps in ie7

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-7

I'm trying to put together a simple slideshow, and I'm struggling a little with internet explorer 7.

The navigation is hidden as default incase the user doesn't have js. If they slide, then an arrow will fade in which works perfectly in all browsers but ie7. In ie7, the whole slideshow jumps down a few pixels - I believe it is something to do with display: none being set and then changed upon fadeIn but I can't quite figure it out.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">

        <nav class="home-slideshow">
            <a href="#" onclick="return false"><img src="img/arrow-left.gif" class="arrow-left" height="22" width="13"></a>
            <a href="#" onclick="return false"><img src="img/arrow-right.gif" class="arrow-right" height="22" width="13"></a>
        </nav>

        <ul class="home-slideshow">
            <li>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/slide.jpg" alt="slide" title="slide" height="302" width="960"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/slide.jpg" alt="slide" title="slide" height="302" width="960"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/slide.jpg" alt="slide" title="slide" height="302" width="960"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div> <!-- end wrap -->
```

JS:

```
// home feature slideshow

    // add navigation
    $('.arrow-right').show();

    // navigation
    $('.arrow-right').on('click', (function() {

        if ($(':animated').length) {
            return false;
        }

        ul = $('ul.home-slideshow');

        noOfSlides = 3;
        width = noOfSlides * 960;
        lastSlide = width - 960;
        currentPos = parseInt(ul.css('margin-left'));

        ul.css('width', width);

        ul.animate({
            "margin-left": currentPos - 960
        }, 1500, "easeInOutQuint", function() {

            if (ul.css('margin-left') == '-' + lastSlide + 'px') {
                $('.arrow-right').fadeOut();
            } else {
                $('.arrow-left').fadeIn();
            } // end if

        }); // end animate

    })); // end arrow-right click

    $('.arrow-left').on('click', (function() {

        if ($(':animated').length) {
            return false;
        }

        ul = $('ul.home-slideshow');

        noOfSlides = 3;
        width = noOfSlides * 960;
        lastSlide = width + 960;
        currentPos = parseInt($(ul).css('margin-left'));

        ul.css('width', width);

        ul.animate({
            "margin-left": currentPos + 960
        }, 1500, "easeInOutQuint", function() {

            if (ul.css('margin-left') == '0px') {
                $('.arrow-left').fadeOut();
            } else {
                $('.arrow-right').fadeIn();
            } // end if

        }); // end animate

    })); // end arrow-left click
```

CSS:

```
/* Feature Slideshow */
ul.home-slideshow {
    height: 302px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

    ul.home-slideshow li {
        float: left;
    }

    /* Navigation */
    nav.home-slideshow {
        position: relative;
        width: 960px;
    }

    .arrow-left, .arrow-right {
        background: #003592;
        -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
        box-sizing: content-box;
        display: none;
        height: 22px;
        padding: 6px;
        top: 126px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 13px;
        z-index: 1;
    }
        .arrow-right {
            right: 0px;
        }
        .arrow-left {
            left: 0px;
        }
```

Can anyone suggest a fix to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be this way: (although everything looks perfect)

Try moving Ul home-slideshow up and move nav below it and see if this works:

```
<div class="wrap">

    <ul class="home-slideshow">
        <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="img/slide.jpg" alt="slide" title="slide" height="302" width="960"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="img/slide.jpg" alt="slide" title="slide" height="302" width="960"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="img/slide.jpg" alt="slide" title="slide" height="302" width="960"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <nav class="home-slideshow">
        <a href="#" onclick="return false"><img src="img/arrow-left.gif" class="arrow-left" height="22" width="13"></a>
        <a href="#" onclick="return false"><img src="img/arrow-right.gif" class="arrow-right" height="22" width="13"></a>
    </nav>

</div> <!-- end wrap -->
```

Comment: This appears to work but if I do that, the arrows disappear. What CSS would I need to change to make them appear above again?

Comment: may be try with z-index. make higher z-index of nav and lower to ul.home-slider

Comment: Thanks, that was the first thing I tried but it still didn't show up. I'll continue to play around.

Comment: I actually just changed the slideshow and nav to float, then used a negative top-margin. Not particularly pretty but works perfectly now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Hi 0Neji i had some probs with z-indexes in one of my projects i used this code snippet to solve the ie z-index issues:

See if this works or you can play with the numbers here:(i played too to get this work for me)

```
var zIndexNumber = 1000;
$('li').each(function() {
  $(this).css('zIndex', zIndexNumber);
      zIndexNumber -= 10;
});
```